# Using vue router BeforeRouteEnter method to wait for http request to complete

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, beforerouteenter

Hi I'm trying to make it so that when a user opens a page it won't open until the data from the server is successfully retrieved so that it won't appear after 0.5s or so after the user enters.

To do this I read that I need to use BeforeRouteEnter but I'm having trouble finding information on how to properly use this, especially with waiting for my REST API to complete its request.

Here's the method I want to wait to complete before routing to my new component:

```
 async getThread() {
            const response = await postsService.fetchOneThread({
                id: this.blockId,
                topic: this.topicId,
                thread: this.postId
            });
            this.thread = response.data;
        }
```

so once this.thread = response.data only then do I want the page to display.

An important thing to note is that I am also passing through URL parameters to get the data which is the topic/black/post ID.

Here is my getUrlParam method also

```
url() {
            let x = this.$route.params.topic.split('-');
            this.topicId = x[0];

            let y = this.$route.params.id.split('-');
            this.blockId = y[0];

            let post = this.$route.params.thread.split('-');
            this.postId = post[1];

            this.getThread();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the `await` keyword everywhere you want to "wait" for an asynchronous function to finish.

Comment: ? this isn't my question

Comment: What is your question then? You just need to call `getThread` from `beforeRouteEnter` using `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `getThread` inside `beforeRouteEnter`

```
beforeRouteEnter: (to, from, next) => {
  postsService.fetchOneThread({
    id: this.blockId,
    topic: this.topicId,
    thread: this.postId
  }).then( response => {
     //store the data somewhere accessible
     next()
  })
},
```

A few notes:

- I don't think `beforeRouteEnter` can be async, so I'm using `then` to get the response
- the component is not yet ready, so you can't access it yet, you need to save the information some other place so it can be read by the component. I'd suggest using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for this.

If you decide to use `Vuex` than you need to add a mutation and call it from the promise's callback.

```
store.commit('ADD_THREAD', response.data)
```

Comment: `beforeRouteEnter` can be async ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-benz-91nuz?file=/src/views/User.vue)).